# How can I see the sky dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since version 1.6 or early 1.7, Minecraft has referenced the sky dimension in its script. Is it accessible?

If so, how can I play in the sky dimension in single player or SMP?

Comment: Is there an issue with making the question more readable?

Comment: Yup, it's not a biome but a land, that's why I made a rollback.

Comment: How about the rest of the edits? Were they unacceptable as well?

Comment: I have changed the [tag:Sky-Dimension] tag to [tag:Minecraft-Sky-Dimension] for consistency (See [tag:Minecraft-Nether])

Comment: Shouldn't it be aether?

Comment: @Warface — I've created [a mod](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12962279/Minecraft/mods/1.7.3/xa.class) which replaces the normal Minecraft world with the sky dimension. Just copy `xa.class` into your `minecraft.jar` as you would any other mod, but **back up your .minecraft folder first!** You'll want to be able to uninstall it after you're done exploring and if you load one of your existing worlds while it's installed, you'll get some *very* odd chunks generating. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *is* possible to experiment with the sky dimension, but only through the use of mods.  The [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sky_Dimension) details [how to go about this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mods/Aether_Collaboration).  Keep in mind, though, that this is experimental and should not be trusted or considered very well tested.

Comment: Yeah but I see lots of videos of people actually playing on it. There's no mobs and ressource are limited but it's actually possible to generate that map... just need to find how :S

Comment: @Warface - See my update, I found information that proved my original post wrong

Comment: This isn't actually Notch's official sky dimension. It's a mod that partially inspired the official work that (to my knowledge) has not yet been released in any Minecraft update.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I would believe that, I thought it unlikely notch would leave an unfinished feature in the game

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: On the wiki it says, "Notch left data in for an early prototype of the sky dimension in Beta 1.6 and 1.7." Which wouldn't be the first time that he's done so, although I'm not sure that the Aether mod uses that prototype.

Comment: I've upvoted for the effort but you haven't tried to look for a way to create it, by pointing me to mods or script that could helped me to access it. Anyway thanks @Dave McClelland and all others :D

Comment: @Warface I'm not sure what you mean.  If you click the link that says "how to go about this," it directs to the Aether Mod page on minecraft wiki.  In the "Installation" section, it lists the necessary mods and steps for installation

Comment: Yeah But this mod is a complete change in the gameplay no ? More armor, creatures, animals, weapons... and doesn't seems to be SMP neither. I liked you help, don't be sad it's just that this mod is not exactly what I was looking for that's all. :D

Comment: @Warface — I've poked at the world generator code some, and it shouldn't be hard to make a mod which replaces the Nether with the sky prototype.  I'll give it a shot when I get home tonight and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Notch's plans for the Sky dimension were put on halt during Beta 1.7.3. Since then, the world ID and code for the sky were taken by the End dimension. Even it there was a "sky portal" it would take you to the End. The Sky world does not exist and does not get created at the world start of SSP or SMP.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found this for Bukkit on SMP -> [Dreamlands](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tp-misc-dreamland-v2-4-skylands-are-in-your-dreams-permissions-1000.24188/)

This plugins makes in sort that when you sleep in a bed, you get to the skylands. Creating a new world on your server, you can access it through any beds at night or with another plugins for portals, link it to this world.

So it's confirmed, their is some early prototype of the skylands in the version 1.7.3 since I was able to generate it with this plugins. The islands are floating and the clouds are in the Void.

Pretty awesome ! :D