# How do we set up a minecraft lan server to support the Aether mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-aether

Minecraft servers normally use a dedicated .jar file that the dedicated server calls all its data from.. where is this located so i can incorperate the Aether Support, or is there other means of getting Aether support in the Minecraft Dedicated Server App?

Comment: @Warface If you think this question is a duplicate, you should flag it as such and maybe leave a comment if you want to announce your decision. That duplicate box is added by the Community user once the question is actually closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28219/how-can-i-see-the-sky-dimension @lunboks it was already flagged too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aether mod does not support SMP. ([source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/495374-173-aether-collaboration-mod-v102-new-mobs-fixes-items-and-features/))

```
The official forum does not state anything about SMP
```

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft Lan servers are listen servers, not dedicated, so theoretically, if both players have the same mods installed, it *should* work, all one would have to do to test this is have one player start a single player with lan open, and have another player on lan attempt to join them.